# Deinstall Xamarin completely

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have a pc with a C:/ drive that can only handle 100GB. For school I needed to download Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 for a hackaton (so I only needed it 1 day). It took a while to get 20GB of free space in my C:/ drive (because of course, it wouldn't just download on my D:/ or an external drive), after the installation, less than 1 GB remained. But I still needed to do an update for Xamarin... after deinstalling some Adobe programs, I still didn't get enough memory for that update, so I gave up and ended up pair programming.

Now, after the hackaton, I wanted to remove Xamarin as quickly as possible. I looked up what I had to remove and I did, now only 6,3GB free space remains. Meaning that more than 15GB is still taken by something.

I looked up several sites, I even tried to find hidden files in my regedit, but I didn't succeed in getting my space back. It seems that no one really wants to get rid of Xamarin alone.
The problem is that I still need Visual Studio 15 for ASP.NET for school, so I would rather not deinstall my visual Studio completely as it takes a while to completely install it again.

Has anyone an idea what files I can remove that is installed together with Xamarin, or what I can try to get my C:/ drive to breathe again?

Comment: You might still have a copy of the Android NDK and SDK that came down with Xamarin.  If you don't want them, please take a look in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android.  It certainly won't amount to 15GB, but it might help you free up a few gig.

Comment: Programs like WinDirStat can help you here to figure out what and where space is taken up on your computer.